# Does Entity size matter for performance in EF Core with DB first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm writing a ASP.NET Core Web API project. As a data source It will be using existing (and pretty big) database. But not entire database. The API will use only some of the tables and even in these tables it will not use all the columns.

Using Reverse engineering and scaffolding I was able to generate `DbContext` and Entity classes... and it got me thinking. There is a table with 30 columns (or more). I'm using this table, but I only need 5 columns.

My question is:
**Is there any advantage of removing 25 unused columns from C# entity object?** Does it really matter?

The advantage of leaving them there unused is that in case of someone wants to add new functionality that will need one of them, he will not need to go to the db and reverse engineer needed columns (there are there already).

The advantage of removing unused is... ?

**EDIT: Here is the sample code:**

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    public FooContext(DbContextOptions<FooContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

[Table("item")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [Column("itemID", TypeName = "int")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name", TypeName = "varchar(255)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public ItemDto GetItem(int id)
{
    var item = _fooContext.Items.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    // Here I have item with two fields: Id and Name. 

    var itemDto = _mapper.Map<ItemDto>(item);
    return itemDto;
}
```

Obviously I'm curious about more complex operations. Like... when item entity is being included by other entity. For example:

`_foo.Warehouse.Include(i => i.Items)`

or other more complex functions on `Item` entity

Comment: If you don't query for the columns you; A. don't send data over the network and B. you don't have data in memory you don't need.  Since we don't know the sizes of the columns, it's not really possible to determine how much of an advantage this is.

Comment: @ErikPhilips By "size" I actually meant the number of columns/fields in the Table/Entity. I was thinking about scenario when you include Item entity for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entity needs to match what's in the database, i.e. you need a property to match each column (neglecting any shadow properties). There's no choice here, as EF will complain otherwise.

However, when you actually query, you can select only the columns you actually need via something like:

```
var foos = await _context.Foos
    .Select(x => new
    { 
       Bar = x.Bar,
       Baz = z.Baz
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Alternatively, if you don't need to be able to insert/update the table, you can instead opt to use `DbQuery<T>` instead of `DbSet<T>`. With `DbQuery<T>`, you can use anything class you want, and project the values however you like, via `FromSql`.

Comment: I'm not sure you are correct with *"There's no choice here, as EF will complain otherwise"*. I have a table "item" with lots of columns in the database, probably around 30. I created entity with only two columns: Id and Name. EF Core works without any problems. Look at my EDIT in the question.

Comment: @IshThomas It depends on what do you include in "works". Query, update (only the properties you have included), delete - ok. Insert though won't work if the table columns not included in the entity have not setup meaningful default at the database table level. Chris sort of mentioned that at the end of the answer. The only correction is that using `QbQuery<T>` is not mandatory - the same can be done with `DbSet<T>` under the aforementioned insert constraints. (in fact in EF Core 3.0 query types will be consolidated with entity types and will be called keyless entities).

Comment: All non-nullable, non-defaulting columns need to be mapped in an entity in order to be able to insert a new row using an entity. For read/update purposes you can use a partial entity definition even excluding non-null-ables. (must have PK though) A limitation of EF is that within a DbContext only 1 entity definition can be associated to a table. So to use a simplified entity you need to use a bounded context. (Separate DbContext to serve the lightweight entity) For Reads, just use projection as Chris outlined. For bulk updates/writes, bounded contexts with featherweights is a viable option.